# Writing to xml file using Java with symbols for line break?

Tags: java, xml

Basically, I am trying to add in a line break from code to an xml file. If i use \n it will throw an error. I tried using `<br />` or `&#xA;` but to no avail.

I want to write: "hello \n HI!" into a XML tag which becomes:

```
<tag>Hello
Hi</tag>
```

Comment: Can't you use <![CDATA[Hello\nHi]]> or similar?

Comment: It helps to provide us with the error. But you could try to replace \n with \\n

Comment: You can use `"Hello" + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ) + "world"` which gives OS dependent line separator.

Comment: “If i use \n it will throw an error.” What error?  The backslash is not a special character in XML.  `<tag>Hello\nHi</tag>` is completely valid XML.

Comment: Basically `"\n"` (or "\r\n" on Windows) and `&#xA;` are fine. It could be that there is a DTD or schema bound to that `<tag>` - for instance for a date field or such. Maybe you can mention the error. Also edit by hand, and validate the XML.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, i think i found out where my error is! It's a javafx exception instead of an xml error!

Answer (score -1):

**If you are writing to a file. then you can use "\r\n" or System.getProperty( "line.separator" )**

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        String xml= "<tag>Hello "+System.getProperty("line.separator")+" world!</tag>";

        File dest = new File("D:\\sample.xml");
        if(!dest.exists())dest.createNewFile();

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);

        os.write(xml.getBytes());

        os.close();
 }
```

Comment: welcome to SO. It is a good practice to use `System.getProperty( "line.separator" )` rather than using ` \r\t ` directly.

Comment: Did you mean `\r\n`?  [`\t` is a tab character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-EscapeSequence);  is has nothing to do with line breaks.

Comment: Thank you :)  @dush